# Complex Regex Pattern for Postcodes

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a regex pattern to only allow 'LL' UK postcodes and I use it with parsley JS with the 'pattern' tag.

```
data-parsley-pattern="/^[L]{2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/"
```

I now need to have a complex regex that would allow all 'LL' postcodes and certain 'CH' postcodes.

Can someone please tell me what this would look like? It's way too complex for me.

```
CH1 6B <---- 1 letter after the B
CH1 6Q <---- 1 letter after the Q
CH4 9A <---- 1 letter after the 0
CH4 9B <---- 1 letter after the 0
CH4 0 <---- 2 letters after the 0
CH5 <---- All variations like the 'LL'regex  [0-9][0-9A-Z]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}
CH6 <---- All variations like the 'LL' regex  [0-9][0-9A-Z]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}
CH7 <---- All variations like the 'LL' regex  [0-9][0-9A-Z]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}
CH8 <---- All variations like the 'LL' regex  [0-9][0-9A-Z]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}
```

The idea is if the postcode starts with 'LL' carry on using the normal regex, if the postcode starts with CH use a different pattern for everything after 'CH'

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only just started with `RegEx` (so this could be flawed) but maybe something along these lines:

```
^(LL\d[0-9A-Z]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|CH1 (6B|6Q)[A-Z]|CH4 (9A|9B)[A-Z]|CH4 0[A-Z]{2}|CH[5-8][0-9A-Z]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2})$
```

Comment: hi @JvdV I think that's working perfectly! Thank you! where do I add the global quantifier and for what reason?

Comment: @Third_Hyperion, never mind. I was trying to test it on a multi-line which needed the global quantifier to return all valid codes. Glad it works.

Comment: Also, kudos to @ZPiDER, as he has a good explaination on why it would work.

Comment: Yes thank you to both of you, would have never figured that out!

Comment: Please could you help me again? 

How would I do similar and only target the following postcodes all encompassing LA7, LA8, LA9, LA11, LA12, LA21, LA22, LA23, CA10, CA11 and CA12

Comment: Is this right? /^(LA[7-9]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|LA(11|12|21|22|23)? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|CA(10|11|12)? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2})$/

Comment: @Third_Hyperion, you can use `^(?:LA(?:[789]|[12][12]|23)|CA1[012])$`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly get what the CH-expression should be but maybe i can give you some pointers.

```
/^(LL\d[0-9A-Z]? ?\d[A-Z]{2}|CH1 (6B|6Q)[0-9A-Z]|CH[2-9] \d[0-9A-Z]{1,2})$/
```

`/^(A|B)$/` will match either `A` or `B`. A and B may be more complex as well. You can use that to check for multiple different patterns, each separated with a `|`.

`[L]{2}` is a badly legible `LL`, keep it simple :)

`\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`

Comment: Hi, @ZPiDER thank you, that has put me halfway there. Let me try to explain the CH expression better - CH5, CH6, CH7, CH8 works as normal, using the expression you just provided, however, for example the CH1 should only match for CH1 6B* and CH1 6Q* but NOT for CH1 6F* - does that make sense?

Comment: @Third_Hyperion, i changed the answer to do that. notice you may nest the (A|B) expressions to keep your RE compact (but not necessarily more legible ;) )

Comment: Please could you help me again? 

How would I do similar and only target the following postcodes all encompassing LA7, LA8, LA9, LA11, LA12, LA21, LA22, LA23, CA10, CA11 and CA12